# Dúvida sobre HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html

Estou desenvolvendo uma plataforma Web para criação de uns questionários específicos. Por enquanto, só quero ler o enunciado das perguntas e a lista de alternativas de respostas, dependendo do tipo da pergunta. Tenho o seguinte formulário:

[image]

Eu queria fazer uma graça, de modo que enquanto a pessoa vai escrevendo no campo "Enunciado", o balãozinho de fala do personagem ao lado direito vai sendo preenchido com o que a pessoa estiver digitando no campo referido.

Alguém tem alguma ideia pra me ajudar?

- Extra: Terminando essa parte de Front-End, preciso fazer um certo processamento com estes dados. Já pesquisei um pouco sobre desenvolvimento Back-End, uso de AJAX, etc. Se alguém puder me recomendar algum framework pra ajudar nessa conexão ou coisa do tipo, dar uma luz de como prosseguir pra integrar o Back-End com o que já está feito, é bem vindo.

Edit1: Acabei de perceber que só consigo clicar no campo de texto "Título do questionário", para entrar com texto. Nos demais, "Enunciado" e "Atributos" não consigo clicar para entrar com texto. Não aparece aquele "ponteiro" de digitação ao clicar do mouse. Segue o código (tem umas coisas incompletas de angularjs que eu tava testando, só ignora).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>



    <body>

        <div ng-app="meuApp" ng-controller="principalCtrl">


            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div class ="center-block">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="tituloQ">Título do questionário:</label>
                                    <input type="text" ng-model="tituloQue" name="tituloQ" id="tituloQ"/>
                                    <hr>

                                    <h1>Hello {{tituloQue}}!</h1>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div class ="center-block">
                                <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
                                    <li class="dropdown">
                                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Criar pergunta
                                            <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu ">
                                            <li><a href="#tab_PA" data-toggle="tab">  Criar pergunta texto livre</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#tab_PME" data-toggle="tab"> Criar pergunta multipla escolha</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#tab_PEU" data-toggle="tab">  Criar pergunta escolha única</a></li> 
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>                           
                                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab_T" aria-controls="tab_T" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Temas</a></li>
                                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab_P" aria-controls="tab_P" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Pré-Visualizar</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="panel-body">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="tab-content col-md-6" > 

                                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab_T">
                                        Temas
                                    </div>

                                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab_P">
                                        Pré-visualização
                                    </div>




                                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tab_PA">

                                        <div class="form-group">


                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Enunciado:</label>
                                                <input type="text" ng-model="enunciadoPA">
                                                <br>
                                                <h1>Hello {{enunciadoPA}}!</h1>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="atributoPA">Atributos:</label><br>
                                                    <input type="text" name="atributoPA" id="atributoPA"> <br>
                                                    <small id="emailHelp" class="text-muted">Separe os atributos com traço, ' - '.</small>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <input type="submit" name="addP" value="Adicionar Pergunta">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab_PME">

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="enunciadoPME">Enunciado:</label><br>
                                            <input type="text" name="enunciadoPME" id="enunciadoPME">
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="atributoPME">Atributos:</label><br>
                                            <input type="text" name="atributoPME" id="atributoPME"> <br>
                                            <small id="emailHelp1" class="text-muted">Separe os atributos com traço, ' - '.</small>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="opcoesPME">Grupo de opções:</label><br>
                                            <input type="text" name="opcoesPME" id="opcoesPME"> <br>
                                            <small id="emailHelp2" class="text-muted">Separe as opções de resposta com traço, ' - '.</small>
                                        </div>

                                        <input type="submit" name="addP" value="Adicionar Pergunta">
                                    </div>

                                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab_EU">
                                        <form action="/efetivar.php" method="POST">

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="enunciadoPEU">Enunciado:</label><br>
                                                <input type="text" name="enunciadoPEU" id="enunciadoPEU">
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="atributoPEU">Atributos:</label><br>
                                                <input type="text" name="atributoPEU" id="atributoPEU"> <br>
                                                <small id="emailHelp3" class="text-muted">Separe os atributos com traço, ' - '.</small>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="opcoesPEU">Grupo de opções:</label><br>
                                                <input type="text" name="opcoesPEU" id="opcoesPEU"> <br>
                                                <small id="emailHelp3" class="text-muted">Separe as opções de resposta com traço, ' - '.</small>
                                            </div>

                                            <input type="submit" name="addP" value="Adicionar Pergunta">


                                        </form>
                                    </div>


                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                                    <img src="imagens/feliz.png" width="350" height="280" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- SCRIPTS/BIBLIOTECAS -->
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

            <!-- SCRIPTS ANGULARJS -->
            <script src="js/app.js"></script> 
            <script src="js/controller.js"></script>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Voce esta usando Jquery ou só Javascript puro?

Comment: Posta seu Html aqui para ajudar

Comment: Poderia usar algum framework Js que usa data-binding: Angular Js, VueJs. Isso facilitaria muito seu trabalho, pesquise por alguma destas ferramentas

Comment: Sem código fica complicado de ajudar.

Comment: coloque seu codigo

Comment: Editei a pergunta com outra dúvida e adicionei o HTML.

Comment: @AcreanoDingo-Dingo se vais mudando a pergunta à medida que descobres erros as respostas vão ficar todas inutilizadas. Por favor coloca 1 pergunta e se descobrires outros problemas que não souberes resolver faz uma nova pergunta se não houver já resposta no site para esse tipo de problema.

Comment: Coloca o seu site no Codepen.io, com CSS, todos os javascripts adicionado, para conseguirmos reproduzir o problema real. Da maneira que está não da pra entender. Mas SUPONHO que é algum problema de CSS, onde alguma div sua está passando por cima do INPUT. Mas pra ter certeza precisamos do código completo.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar AngularJS, nesse caso. Você pode fazer facilmente, basta antes de mais nada adicionar o [angular.min.js](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js) em seu HTML. Um exemplo básico que já é exibido na própria [página inicial do angularjs](https://angularjs.org/), que supre sua necessidade:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <label>Name:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
      <hr>
      <h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Um bom framework backend que recomendo é Django. Um framework Python bem simples de usar e bem fácil de instalar. Já existe boa parte da documentação em português: https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/1.11/

Comment: Obrigado, Guilherme!

Comment: Adicionei outra dúvida/erro no tópico!

Comment: Coloca o site no codepen.io para reproduzirmos o erro exato. Abraços!